# Changing the text for lightbox with Virtuemart

Tags: joomla, lightbox, virtuemart

I'm using the lightbox on my product pages on a Danish site ( I have language packs installed for Joomla and Virtuemart) however all text output for the Lightbox plugin is in English. I thought there might be a language file for the Lightbox however I've been unable to locate one. Furthermore I've taken a look through some of the files I thought might be responsible for the Lightbox however I've not been able to find anything there which might be responsible for outputting the text. (thinking I'd just edit in these core files )

Has anyone had any experience making similar changes or the knowledge about how I may go about making these changes ?

Many thanks in advance.

Q.

Joomla 1.5.20 with VM 1.1.5

Answer (score 0):

The lightbox text in the pop up is leveraged from the title="" attribute within the link  element. Unfortunately it depends on the language translation extension or method you are using but ultimately as most of them translate a page after it has been posted then the title="" attribute will be in the original language and not part of the translated text. However if you are using the site with it loading by default in the given language then the text will be translated.

Lastly the title="" attribute is either set via the HTML view source from the WYSIWYG editor or from the editor settings when you create the lightbox pop up.

What this means is that more likely then not you will need to alter the lightbox title attributes manually and type them in the translated language of your choice.